# Thinking Sphinx and ActiveRecord default_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, thinking-sphinx

Is there any way I can skip applying the ActiveRecord::Base's default_scope to the search result of Thinking Sphinx?

https://gist.github.com/1378847

Answer (score 0):

<s>Just use `unscoped` method before calling search.</s>

See more [info](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/unscoped/class)

**EDIT**

See https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb#L89. Add and option `:ignore_default` to skip scopes. (But this uses Sphinx scopes so need to be checked).

Comment: it doesn't work, I've tried `Article.unscoped.search(...)` and `Article.unscoped {Article.search(...)}`, all of them returned the scoped results

Comment: @Marc, don't you think that's a bug of Thinking Sphinx, the "@" before "options" is missing on line 89

Comment: `Article.search(keywords, :ignore_default => true)` returns the scoped results, no luck

Comment: As you can see from [here](https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb#L352), it defaults the `ignore_default` to be true

Comment: Get the to_sql on 'Article.search(keywords)'. Then we can investigate if there issue in sql, or in indexes.

Comment: seems I can not call to_sql on the `Article.search` directly

Comment: [here](https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/blob/master/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb#L951) indicates that `ignore_default` is used to ignore the sphinx's default scope but ActiveRecord::Base's default scope